# How to use AbstractList

Tags: java, data-structures

I am newer to Java just started it a while back. I am trying to make chat messenger (Client-Server) and I need a data structure in which I can store online users (One socket and one String containing Username). Now I did a lot of research and thought AbstractList could help me decently, but I faced a problem rather quickly

```
public class Collections <E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    private int size;
    private E[] list;

    public Collections() {
        size = 0;
        list = new E[50];
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return list[index];
    }
    @Override
    public boolean add(E element) {


        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.length;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collections <String>obj = new Collections();
        obj.add(new String("1"));
        obj.add(new String("5"));

        System.out.println("Size = " + obj.size());
    }
}
```

This is my code and frankly I couldn't get a way around the add function...
I tried using

```
list = new E[50];
```

but that gives generic initialization error. In short I have no idea how to initialize the list object.
So now I have Three questions:

1. Is my approach to creating a list of all the clients on Server good?
2. What should I do with the add() function?
3. Why are there '' twice in the first line? Obviously it is a template but wouldn't you need it only once? Obviously you need it both places so what is the first one for and what is the second one for? (The Tutorial I learnt from didn't quiet explain it)

Comment: You cannot create a generic array directly.  Use an `ArrayList<E>` instead.

Comment: You should start by reading Programming java for beginner. Not only do you not understand the java syntax, from the code above you don't even know the idea behind object oriented programming. Before you jump into this, please do some reading first.

Comment: @5gon12eder could you demonstrate sample code on how to use ArrayList?

Comment: I suggest you get started [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html). Also see @[VivinPaliath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26305852/1392132)'s answer.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thanks I will read it.

Comment: @5gon12eder I've read the material and I must say it's an excellent read. And I've finally had some concept of OOP in Java obviously I had little before. Thanks! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add items to a list you can do this, you don't need to create your own list class

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("Peter");
myList.add("Susan");
```

Now if you want to create a list of all you username and sockets you could use a Map. Something like

```
Map<String, Socket> myMap = new HashMap<String, Socket>();
myMap.put("Peter", petersSocket);
myMap.put("Susan", susansSocket);
```

This will allow you to retrieve sockets by username

```
Socket petes = myMap.get("Peter");
```

Or you could instead create you own Username and Socket class

```
public class UsernameSocketPair{
  private String name;
  private Socket socket;
  public UsernameSocketPair(String name, Socket socket){
     this.name = name;
     this.socket = socket;
  }

  public String getName(){
     return name;
  }

  public Socket socket(){
     return socket;
  }
}
```

Then this can be put in a list like

```
List<UsernameSocketPair> myList = new ArrayList<UsernameSocketPair>();
myList.add(new UsernameSocketPair("Peter", petersSocket));
```

Whether this is a good idea or not, it depends on the rest of your code and how its structured.

To answer the questions explicitly:

1. It depends on the rest of your code and how its structured.
2. First don't use E[] use Object[] and cast to E when you 'get' the element. That way you can instantiate (e.g. Object[] list = new Object[20];
3. The E is in the class declaration twice be cause you are extending a class of type AbstractList and you are parametrising your class by E. You could do, for example.

The following:

```
public class MyList extends AbstractList<String>{

}
```

Below is a really noddy example of how to implement a concrete version of abstract list parametrised as you wanted

```
public class MyList <E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    private Object[] list = new Object[10];
    private int size = 0;


    public E get(int i){
        if(i >= size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("duh!");
        return (E)list[i];
    }

    public boolean add(E e){
        if(size >= list.length){
            Object[] newList = new Object[list.length + 10];
            System.arraycopy(list,0, newList, 0, list.length);
            list = newList;
        }
        list[size] = e;
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    public int size(){
        return size;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> l = new MyList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            l.add(""+i);
        }
        System.out.println(l.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I needed but If I may ask why prefer Maps over ArrayList or AbstractList?

Comment: Sure, maps are useful if you want to retrieve the value by the key. So if you don't know what index in the list it is you can retrieve by the value (in this example "Peter" rather than 1). Otherwise you'll have to scan the whole list.

Comment: Hmmm. Got It Thanks a lot! But just to be clear it is infact a Hash Table and since userid is unique we can fetch the value giving the username but the question is how or when are you telling that String is the key here?
And further more how do you represent String in forms of numbers? From what I understand HashKey works on a number rather than Strings. Correct me if I am worng.

Comment: The difference between a map and table is that table is threadsafe and as a result is slower. That's the java distinction in comp sci I think table and map and dictionary are all interchangeable. The key is the first parameter in the put method. Java uses the hashcode method on all objects as the key in a HashMap, you'll need to override it in most cases if you are using a custom class in your hashmap (or table) key.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some design issues which I think stem from the fact that you are a beginner:

- There is no need to extend `AbstractList<E>` unless you really require some special type of list. You can simply use a concrete implementation of `List<T>` like `LinkedList<T>` or `ArrayList<T>`.
- Your code has a design problem. Your server **is not a list**. But this is what your code says, since your main class is extending `AbstractList<E>`. Instead, your server should be **using a list**. So the correct approach is to use an internal `List<T>` instance that keeps track of your clients.

Your approach is fundamentally wrong, so I would suggest reading up on some beginner texts on Java and Object-Oriented Programming in general. From your code it seems like you have some misconceptions as to what OOP actualy is.

Comment: This is not my Server class I used it only to understand the concept of Collection class in Java but I need it to provide a data structure. And I did consider ArrayList at first but didn't think it was the better option so moved on to AbstractList. As I mentioned I need it to keep a list of all the online clients (Socket and UserName).

Comment: Could you explain what's wrong with ArrayList for your needs?

Comment: @Vivin now that I've read 5gon12eder 's link I understand the working of ArrayList better and realised there is nothing wrong with using it. Infact I just implemented it. Thanks!